# Customizing Solr for optimization

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I am newbie to java but an expert in lamp.
I am using solr for my search requirement.

However i need to perform a real time search for online user + some criteria.

Current implementation:
I am sending all online user ids (+ offcourse other search criteria) in post request which is very slow.

To overcome this i must do some internal code changes.

Can someone guide me how to go about this change and is there any tutorial available

Comment: Are you using solr in your current implementation or others technologies?

Answer (score -2):

Optimizing Solr is very easy. In fact Solr guys have themselves come up with a wiki page for boosting [performance of Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors).

You can tune Solr in several ways. The basic tuning you should be looking at are as below:

- Optimize Java params passed to Solr eg: `-Xmx2048m -Xms512m”(2G/512M)`
- Tune the hardware which matches the requirement.
- Configure enough `SolrCache` which is required.
- Move `Zookeeper`, if using, to another disk. If the index is huge then number of I/O call from Solr to - `Zookeeper` will degrade the assembly performance.
- Increase the `Zookeeper` timeout period.
- Log `GC` times, I found out pauses of upto 20s on `Zookeeper` boxes.
- Optimize Solr search Queries.
- Use the recommendations to tune the heap from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ShawnHeisey#GC_Tuning

Also, Have a look at the [guide to Solr performance tuning](http://h3x.no/2011/05/10/guide-solr-performance-tuning).

But, in the end, do remember that Solr is not intended for real time search.

Comment: question is how to to do internal changes not to optimize existing parameters